# Problem importing table in R: header file is imported with an extra column

Tags: r

I have the following table (see https://pastebin.com/uXKYF7Yq):

```
        Domain      Phylum          Class   Order   Family  Genus   Species
otu1    Bacteria    Actinobacteria  Coriobacteriia  Coriobacteriales    Coriobacteriaceae   
otu2    Bacteria    Actinobacteria  Coriobacteriia  Coriobacteriales    Coriobacteriaceae                   
otu3    Bacteria    Firmicutes  Clostridia  Clostridiales   Ruminococcaceae
```

And I tried in several way to import it in R, for example using:

```
tab <- read.table(sep="\t", header = TRUE,file="/data/table.txt")
```

For some reason it's correctly interpretin the first column as "rownames", but it's also adding an extra "X" column. My header starts with a "\t" but I can re-format the input as needed.

See screenshot here: https://postimg.cc/6T7mkwRj
Or text view below:

```
             X         Domain         Phylum             Class              Order Family
otu1 Bacteria Actinobacteria Coriobacteriia  Coriobacteriales  Coriobacteriaceae       
otu2 Bacteria Actinobacteria Coriobacteriia  Coriobacteriales  Coriobacteriaceae       
otu4 Bacteria     Firmicutes     Clostridia     Clostridiales    Ruminococcaceae
```

The column with values "Bacteria" should have "Domain" as header, while the column names are shifted.

**UPDATE**
The behaviour was due to malformed input

Comment: I definitely think my question should focus on "how to prepare the input file for this". I'll check better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way to get `read.table` to correctly read the header, which is missing a column, but one option here would be to use `skip=1`, and just skip over the header row.  Then, manually assign the column names.

```
tab <- read.table(sep="\t", header=TRUE, file="/data/table.txt", skip=1)
names(tab) <- c("Obs", "Domain", "Phylum", "Class", "Order", "Family", "Genus", "Species")
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I did this but I wanted to load column names from the file, in case they change for some reason

Comment: Then how about editing the file, or perhaps fixing your upstream source such that it sends you files which R can more easily parse?

Comment: Yes I can fix the input: what change do you suggest?

Comment: Just add a column label over the first column which contains the values `otu1`, `otu2`, etc.  Then, `read.table` should work as you already have it.